# I did a High Resolution Timing in C on Windows? Is it right?

Tags: c, windows, operating-system, performancecounter, countdowntimer

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

TASK (Task2ms)
{
    printf("Hello"):

    SetEvent(Task1);
}

void main()
{
    int arg;
    HANDLE Task1;
    HANDLE HTimer1 =NULL;
    HANDLE HTimerQueue1 = NULL;
    Task1 = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if(NULL == Task1)
    {
        printf("CreateEvent failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    //create a timer queue
    HTimerQueue1 = CreateTimerQueue();
    if(NULL == HTimerQueue1)
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 2;
    }

    //phNewTimer - Pointer to a handle; this is an out value
    //TimerQueue - Timer queue handle. For the default timer queue, NULL
    //Callback - Pointer to the callback function
    //Parameter - Value passed to the callback function
    //DueTime - Time (milliseconds), before the timer is set to the signaled state for the first time 
    //Period - Timer period (milliseconds). If zero, timer is signaled only once
    //Flags - One or more of the next values (table taken from MSDN):

    //set the timer to call the timer routine in 2ms
    if(!CreateTimerQueueTimer( &HTimer1, HTimerQueue1, (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)TASK, &arg, 2,0,0))
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueueTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 3;
    }

    //Do other work here

    printf("Call timer routine in 2 milliseconds...\n");
    // wait for the timeröqueue thread to complete using an event

    if (WaitForSingleObject(Task1, INFINITE) !=WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(Task1);

    //Delete all timers in the timer queue
    if(!DeleteTimerQueue(HTimerQueue1))
        printf("DeleteTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());

    return 0;
}
```

I created a function called Task(task 2ms) which is to be called every 2ms. So I created a timer queue for that. If I do like this then the Task function will be called for every 2ms. Is this right?

Comment: compiler and debugger are My friends...! not yours ?

Comment: could you be precise in your answer!!

Comment: have you compiled your code ?

Comment: it is displaying only once hello.

Comment: *Is this right?* in what sense?  ***you*** can tell us if it compiles and runs (that is "correct" in one sense).  ***you*** can tell us if you get the output you expect.  "Right" has many definitions:  Will it get you an A+ on your homework?  Is it portable to other platforms? Is it accurate? etc, etc.

Comment: How to make the Task function to get called for every 2ms ??

Comment: Is it just me, or `Task2ms` is never used? Also, `Task1` is local to main and not accessible by `Task2ms`.

Comment: how to call that TASK function for every 2ms ??

Answer (score 2):

*... be called for every 2ms. Is this right?*

No, it isn't right.

When setting up a timer queue timer, you need to follow the documentation:

You specified the `DueTime` to be 2 ms!

*DueTime: The amount of time in milliseconds relative to the current time that must  elapse before the timer is signaled for the first time.*

And you specified the the `Period` to be zero!

*The period of the timer, in milliseconds. If this parameter is zero, the timer is signaled once. If this parameter is greater than zero, the timer is periodic. A periodic timer automatically reactivates each time the period elapses, until the timer is canceled.*

You would have to specify `Period` to be 2 ms as well.

But your code isn't handling multiple timer events anyway. It simply ends after the first timer event occurred. So you may have to spend some more time on the code anyway, e.g.:

```
while (1) {
  if (WaitForSingleObject(Task1, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
    printf("2 ms event occurred!\n");
  } else {
    printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    break;
  }
}
```

P.S.: What is`Task2ms`for? And: `printf("Hello"):` would have to be replaced by `printf("Hello\n");` (Use a semicolon as terminator/statement seperator!).
YOu're actually asking about code you never even tried to complile. You should not expect people to be keen to answer such questions.